# NSEntityDescription.entityForName returns nil how can i fix this?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsentitydescription

So i am getting the error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

After some trail and error i think it has to do with `let ent` see

```
func newItem(){

    let context = self.context
    let ent = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("InvoiceList", inManagedObjectContext: context)
     print("New data \(ent) ")//outputs: New data nil 

    let nItem = InvoicesList(entity: ent!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
```

ent seems to be nil, but i can't use ent? as in 
`let nItem = InvoicesList(entity: ent?, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)`

So how can i fix this? The core data entity InvoiceList has attributes but no values at start is this wrong?

Comment: You're using Swift and I betting $10 you didn't namespace the class name when you created the entity. On the right pane where the class name is, you have to add the name space via className: MyProject.InvoiceList

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your Entity is setup using a namespace as noted in the image below. On the right pane where the class name is, you have to add the name space via className: MyProject.InvoiceList

[image]

Comment: hmm, i am trying this but xcode 7 has a slightly different UI and xcode doesn't let me MyProject.InvoicesList. The period is deleted as soon as i hit return/tab so it reads MyProjectInvoicesList???

Comment: ARRGGGh, found it ..................typo issue i had `entityForName("InvoiceList",` and not `entityForName("InvoicesList",`

Comment: Glad to see you found a solution to the issue. In Xcode 7 the module should be set to your project by default (it will be under the module field). In Xcode 6 you had to specify the module as shown above (which is the same thing as the namespace).